# Can someone extend this brief description of the superheterodine radio kit?

Tags: rf, radio

The Tecsun 2P3 radio kit comes with a sheet of paper with the following schema and description, but it doesn't explain too much about all the components. For a novice is  a bit hard to know the sense of all of the pieces, especially those not named. Taking the manual description as starting poing, I would be helpful if someone can extend it for learning purpose.

```
Specifications:
Frequency range: 530kHz~1620kHz
DC supply: Power requirements: DC 3V, two R6 AA batteries
Sensitivity: <1mV/m
Maximum Output: 120mW
Quiescent Current: 7mA

 - Mixing circuit: Mixing circuit is broken down into three sections,
    input tuned circuit, local oscillator and mixer. Magnetic antenna
    inducts radio signal, feeds into a tunning circuit comprised of
    variable capacitator VC4 and L1, where the signal frequency
    indentical to the tunning circuit resonance frequency is selected
    and inducted on L2, this process is called "tunning". L2 feeds the
    tuned radio signal into the base of mixer Q1 (S9018). Q1 has two
    functions.

 - A. Local Oscillator: Q1 working with VC3, C2 and T1, generate an
   equiamplitude sine wave at a frequency 455Khz higher than the tuned
   radio signal.

 - B. Mixer: Q1 mixes L2 inducted radio signal with local generated
   oscillator signal, a 455Khz intermediate signal (IF signal = Local
   Oscillator signal - tuned radio signal = 455Khz) is selected to pass
   the IF transformer T2, in fact, plural frequencies are generated but
   T2 is tuned at 455Khz so only 455Khz IF are passed and all other
   frequencies are filtered. The 455Khz IF is the fed to the IF
   amplifier stage.

 - IF Amplifier: In order to obtain enough gain, 2P3 has two IF
   amplifiers, comprised of Q2, Q3 and peripheral components. 455Khz IF
   signal passes T2, amplified by Q2, passes 455Khz ceramic filter CF1
   and feeds into Q3 for second stage IF amplification. Amplified IF
   signal passes T3 then feeds into detector stage.

 - Detector. When radio signal trasnformed into 455Khz IF signal, only
   carrier wave frequency changes, audio signal riding on carrier
   remains unchanged, but this IF signal is not audible by human ears,
   it must pass a detector to separate audio signal from its carrier,
   this detector is carried out by diode D1 (1N60) and peripheral
   components.

 - Automatic Gain Control: After passing detector D1, IF is filtered by
   C7, R11, part of it feeds through C6, R9, C4 to be stepdown and
   filtered, providing a negative bias to Q2. When radio signal is
   stronger, higher IF output causing Q2 to reduce amplification, it
   works reversely when signal is weaker, hence stronger and weaker
   stations will have relatively similar volume.

 - Audio amplifier: Part of detector output feeds to Audio amplifier IC1
   (CD7368) through C8, to be amplified and fed into speaker.
```

[image]

Comment: A full explanation of every component's purpose would be a bit too broad a question, and nobody knows what you already understand - L/C resonant circuits for example, or frequency mixing, or common-emitter amplifiers. Try a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

I built a [similar kit by Elenco](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008515U1U). While the circuit is probably not the same as yours, the concepts are all the same. [Here is the manual](http://www.elenco.com/admin_data/pdffiles/amfm108k.pdf), which goes into far more detail than your kit. It should help you get started. Complete understanding of a radio receiver requires a lot of knowledge on signals, RF and transistors.